# Kafka consumer offsets handling when shutting down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

With auto commit enabled, when a Java Kafka consumer is asked to shutdown, how does it handle the offsets it already polled, it commits nothing (at least once) ? it commits everything (at most once) ?
Is there a native way to commit partially only processed offsets before “shutting down” the consumer ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`auto.commit` basically works as cron with `auto.commit.interval.ms` setting. Consumer commits in above regular intervals. If you want to control the commit process then disable `auto.commit` property and use commit API. You can use either synchronous or asynchronous commit. By the way synchronous commit will affect your throughout because consumer will wait for acknowledgement from broker before proceeding further polling.

For more detail - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html